# how to view spring csrf token in filter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, csrf, spring-aop

i am using spring mvc 4.3 version. We are using spring csrf which is default.  In one of the scenario i am getting invalid token error, but I see the token whatever I have got the same is been sent to server.  Is there any way I can put log message to see server response to see the csrf token that is generated.  on the UI JSP page i am using  tag and in the page view source I could see the token.  But i want to see in a filter from server side to make sure there is no other token missing on my page.

I have two tabs on my page. Whenever I change tabs I am getting into this token invalid issue. Could you help me how to access this token details in my custom filter.

I tried the AOP like this any changes required?

@Aspect
public class AfterGenerateCsrfTockenAspect {

```
protected transient ITSLogger logger = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
@AfterReturning( 
        pointcut = "org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.generateToken(..)",
        returning = "result"
    )
    public void logGeneratedCsrfToken(Object result) {
        logger.debug("CSRF token was generated.  :::: " + result);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default spring stores csrf token in session.  we can access csrf token from session attributes

```
String key ="org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.CSRF_TOKEN"
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
CsrfToken token =(CsrfToken) session.getAttribute(key);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I can put log message to see server response to see the csrf token that is generated

Yes, AOP to the rescue. For example you can log token each time it was generated:

```
@Aspect
@Slf4j // lombok for logging
public class AfterGenerateCsrfTockenAspect {
    @AfterReturning( // use here FQDN of your Token generator method
        pointcut = "org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository.generateToken(..)",
        returning = "result"
    )
    public void logGeneratedCsrfToken(Object result) {
        log.info("CSRF token '{}' was generated.", result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Maksim, I am new to AOP. could you tell me where to keep the above code in my spring mvc flow? do i need to change anything in this code snippet?

Comment: I have tried with AOP approach in the question section but it did not give me any data